# Offset function for Dynamic Chart causing problems with blank cells

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am using the OFFSET Function to create a dynamic chart for the table depicted in the image below.  Basically on the click of the button labeled "Copy Mean VCD Values" the code copies values from another sheet to the current sheet.  If it encounters any cells with "#DIV/0!" I have it set to put "N/A" instead. But in this case I don't get a dynamic chart.  If in stead of N/A I do "" it creates a dynamic chart but adds junk values "1" to the first set on the graph.  I only get the desired results if I manually delete all the rows containing "N/A" below the last row containing data (See image for details).

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-OfjK6dSRQE8/U2JkdadjedI/AAAAAAAAABk/d8WDLuuC7Lk/w1068-h803-no/Offset+error.PNG

This is the code I am using for the Command Button "Copy Mean VCD Values":

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

        r = 7
        '//j increments the column number
        '//i increments the row number
        '//r is used for taking values from alternate cells(sheet3 column K) rowwise
        For j = 2 To 14
            For i = 7 To 26
                If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("K" & r & "").Text = "#DIV/0!" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, j).Value = "N/A"
                    Else
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, j).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("K" & r & "").Value
                End If
             r = r + 2
            Next i
         Next j


     End Sub
```

If I add the following code it works but it deletes the entire rows before and after the table. See image : https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-WiM8HN61zkM/U2Jz2J_JxjI/AAAAAAAAACw/z4i3hlakyAI/w1598-h442-no/offset+delete+row.PNG

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

        r = 7
        '//j increments the column number
        '//i increments the row number
        '//r is used for taking values from alternate cells(sheet3 column K) rowwise
        For j = 2 To 14
            For i = 7 To 26
                If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("K" & r & "").Text = "#DIV/0!" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, j).Value = "N/A"
                    Else
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, j).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("K" & r & "").Value
                End If
             r = r + 2
            Next i
         Next j

Dim c As Range
Dim SrchRng

Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B7:B26")
Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find("N/A", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Value = ""
Loop While Not c Is Nothing

   End Sub
```

And this is OFFSET Function I am using for Column B in this case:

```
    =OFFSET('Data Summary Template'!$B$7,0,0, COUNTA('Data Summary Template'!$B$7:$B$26),1)
```

Comment: "I am using the OFFSET Function to create a dynamic chart" <-- Can you provide more detail about how you have created the chart, and what are its formula/etc.  Add more screenshots, if necessary.

Comment: I just created list of series using offset function in the NameManager and then used those in the chart. Please see the image for details. Please let me know if you need more info.  Thanks for your help! https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-7xU7uzRu47I/U2JtMsvYcVI/AAAAAAAAAB8/evoBNmrK0H8/w1424-h784-no/dynchart+offset.PNG

Comment: So far I have managed to delete the rows containing "N/A" below the last cell with value.. but I am unable to control the exact range .. it is deleting values in Col A and also beyond Col N https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-rz9fR03fr9U/U2JySKxElaI/AAAAAAAAACU/xoqgsxxn-Q4/w1581-h412-no/offset+delete+row.PNG    I added the code above

Comment: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-WiM8HN61zkM/U2Jz2J_JxjI/AAAAAAAAACw/z4i3hlakyAI/w1598-h442-no/offset+delete+row.PNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't exactly replicate this problem you're having... I think the initial problem must have something to do with the warning regarding invalid references. You should look in to that and figure out the cause, which is probably the cause of "extra" data in your chart.

If deleting the N/A values appears to be working, try something. Instead of:

```
Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B7:B26")
Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find("N/A", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Value = ""
Loop While Not c Is Nothing
```

Do this:

```
Dim tblCell as Range
Dim tbl as ListObject
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
For each tblCell in tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(2).Cells
    If tblCell.Value = "N/A" Then 
        tblCell.Resize(1, tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count - 1).Value = vbNullString
    End If
Next
```